# Invalid Conversion from void(*) to ros::Subscriber function

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Friends,

I am new to ROS and Arduino programming. I am using linux ros system with intel nuc connected to a arduino mega2560 board which then connect to the DSP controller to control the left and right wheels of a robot to move around.

I am trying to program a robot motor to run by sending command through the ros system. It then will translate the command to the arduino mega2560 board and then send signal to the controller.

The problem that i am facing lies with these 2 lines

ros::Subscriber std_msgs::Float32  lwheel_vtarget("lwheel_vtarget", lmotorCb);

ros::Subscriber std_msgs::Float32  rwheel_vtarget("rwheel_vtarget", rmotorCb);

and the error states that

invalid conversion from 'void (*)()' to 'ros::Subscriber<std_msgs::float32>::CallbackT {aka void ()(const std_msgs::Float32&)}' [-fpermissive] ros::Subscriber<std_msgs::float32> lwheel_vtarget("lwheel_vtarget", lmotorCb);

So i dont understand what the error is stating about and require some explanation from your expertise.

Please do state which info you guys need and i will provide it accordingly.

```
#include <ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/Int32.h>
#include <std_msgs/Int16.h>
#include <std_msgs/Float32.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>
 
/**********************/
/*  Variables setup   ****/
/**********************/
 
int interruptPin = 2;
char bufferX[9];
char bufferY[9];
String str = "";
String str_ = "";
bool go = false;
int R;
int L;
std_msgs::Int32 lwheel_msg;
std_msgs::Int32 rwheel_msg;
std_msgs::Float32 lmotor_msg;
std_msgs::Float32 rmotor_msg;
 
/***********************/
/*  Subscribed Nodes    ****/
/***********************/
 
ros::NodeHandle nh;
ros::Publisher lwheel("lwheel", &lwheel_msg);
ros::Publisher rwheel("rwheel", &rwheel_msg);
 
void lmotorCb(){
    Serial1.print("V21=");  // left wheel
    Serial1.println(L);
    Serial1.println("V31=1");
}
void rmotorCb(){
    Serial1.print("V22="); // right wheel
    Serial1.println(R);
    Serial1.println("V31=1");
}
  
ros::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32> lwheel_vtarget("lwheel_vtarget", lmotorCb);
  
ros::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32> rwheel_vtarget("rwheel_vtarget", rmotorCb);
 
void setup() {  
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial1.begin(38400);
  pinMode(interruptPin, INPUT);  
  UCSR1C = (UCSR1C & 0xCF) | (0b11 << 4);  // Enable odd parity
 
  /**********************/
  /*   ROS Node setup   ******/
  /**********************/
  
  nh.getHardware()->setBaud(115200);
  nh.initNode();
  nh.subscribe(lwheel_vtarget);
  nh.subscribe(rwheel_vtarget);
  nh.advertise(lwheel);
  nh.advertise(rwheel);
}
 
void loop() {
  
  //Fetching encoder line
  Serial1.find('=');
 
  str = Serial1.readStringUntil(',');
  str_ = Serial1.readStringUntil('\n');
  
  strncpy(bufferX, str.c_str(), 9); //String to char
  rwheel_msg.data = (unsigned int)strtol(&bufferX[1], NULL, 16);
 
  strncpy(bufferY, str_.c_str(), 9); //String to char
  lwheel_msg.data = (unsigned int)strtol(&bufferY[1], NULL, 16);
  
  lwheel.publish(&lwheel_msg);
  nh.spinOnce();
  rwheel.publish(&rwheel_msg);
  nh.spinOnce();
  
  /**************************************/
  /* Tesiting routine (use when needed) ******/
  /**************************************/
  /**
  Serial.print("Left wheel: ");
  Serial.print(lwheel_msg.data);
  Serial.print(" - Right wheel: ");
  Serial.print(rwheel_msg.data);
  Serial.print("\n");
  */
  
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243411/invalid-conversion-from-void(*)-to-ros::subscriber-function/) by [AyeSir](https://answers.ros.org/users/27930/ayesir/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-09-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What are these lines?

```
ros::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32> lwheel_vtarget("lwheel_vtarget", lmotorCb);
  
ros::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32> rwheel_vtarget("rwheel_vtarget", rmotorCb);
```

Are you trying to create subscriber?

AFAIK you need to create a subscriber using node handle
,e.g. nh.subscribe("topic",queue_size,callback)

See this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber(c%2B%2B)) for more detail

---

Originally posted by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) with karma: 582 on 2016-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AyeSir](https://answers.ros.org/users/27930/ayesir/) on 2016-09-09**:
Yes i am trying to create subscriber. The 2 lines are what my senior had used and implement it into my code which i dont really understand. i have change the 2 lines

ros::Subscriber sub=nh.subscribe("lwheel_vtarget",10, lmotorCb);

ros::Subscriber sub=nh.subscribe("rwheel_vtarget",10, rmotorCb)

**Comment by [AyeSir](https://answers.ros.org/users/27930/ayesir/) on 2016-09-09**:
And the error shown is

invalid use of template-name 'ros::Subscriber' without an argument list      on both lines

So is there any right format for me to write the function correctly?

**Comment by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) on 2016-09-16**:
Please refer to this link --> http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber(c%2B%2B)